# Get all the latitude and longitude set of an area via google maps API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, coordinates

[image]

When I search for a place on google maps, an area precisely, is highlighted on the map, I would like to get the whole set of latitudes and longitudes that make up this area, how can I get them via API? or is there another way or service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openstreetmap.com:

1. Search for the area on [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org)
2. Copy-paste the relation number in http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py
3. Select the correct poly from the list
4. Save as .txt file: each line in the file contains the long and lat coordinates of a geopoint: all geopoints together form the border of the shape (aka the area)